# Performing join on inmemory object using linq is lot slower than inserting them in sql and then writing query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I am optimizing a module in which a report is generated. The input is 7 csv files. Currently the program first truncate the corresponding tables then bulk insert and then finally a sql query execute which gives us the required data. This program belongs to pre linq era.

Now, since there is no use of storing the data in sql server, I am reading the csv file and creating anonymous lists, then I wrote the join logic, and queried the result. what makes me wonder is that this method is 20X slower than the previous one! even when there is no overhead for inserting data.

In sql we do have defined the indexes and keys, so I think the sql performance will be better, however I don't know about what Linq does? Is there any option for similar capability in linq? Can any one give me some insight? Should I go back to previous method of first storing it in sql and using sql for getting the report?
Thanks is advance.

Here Is a sample with two joins which is taking the most time, I have removed many columns

```
var fileinfo = File.ReadAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/massupload/productimages.txt"));
var fileinfo1 = File.ReadAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/massupload/productimages.txt"));
var Items = (from line in fileinfo
            let row = line.Split(',')
            select new
            {
                SKU = row[0].Trim(),
                SupplierId = Convert.ToInt32(row[1].Trim()),
                SupplierItemNo = row[2].Trim()
            }).ToList();

var oits = (from line in fileinfo1
            let row = line.Split(',')
            select new
            {
                Custid=int.Parse(row[0].Trim()),
                SKU = row[01].Trim()
            }).ToList();

var firstjoin = (from i in Items
                join o in oits on i.SKU equals o.SKU
                select new
                {
                    o.Custid,
                    o.SKU,
                    i.SupplierId,
                    i.SupplierItemNo
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Probably because your anonymous object does not store the relational properties in hash tables, thereby joins becoming a seek across the 'tables' to find the appropriate rows.

Comment: No, it dosent. can you guide me how to do that/ any tutorial on net?

Comment: what if you substitute your (physical?) database with an in-memory SqlLite database? That way you will not have to change any business logic, while more or less retaining the performance of relational data.

Comment: It shouldn't be slower at all. The key point is what is the "*join logic*" and how are you "*querying the result*". In LINQ to Objects, the structure of the query is very important because it controls the execution plan (not like in nowadays database SQL queries).

Comment: Is there a reason why you materialize `Items` and `oits` collections using `ToList()`?

Comment: Before I was writing Tolist at the final query, but out of memory exception was getting thrown. This way it is executing but at snail pace.

Comment: Does it help if you use ToDictionary instead of ToList for Items?

Comment: I have not tried To Disctionary, Let me do it.

Comment: In your `oits` set, is the `o.SKU` unique?

Comment: no o.sku is not unique, nor is custid

Comment: Then the queries look ok. What size of data are we talking about (approx. number of rows)? Also, you can start by replacing `File.ReadAllLines` with `File.ReadLines` - currently you are eating too much memory w/o a need.